# Android emulator timezone WARNING on startup

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, macos-high-sierra

I have this warning hanging on the terminal after the avd command:

`emulator: ### WARNING: /etc/localtime does not point to /usr/share/zoneinfo/, can't determine zoneinfo timezone name`

So, I wonder if this is a MacOS(10.13.2) or Android Studio(latest version) problem.

And how to tackle this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue ...

Comment: For the time being, I just ignore the WARNING and set the correct timezone via android system settings and so far no irregularities shown.

Answer (score 12):

Running command below seems to have resolved that warning, note that my timezone is `Africa/Johannesburg`, replace it with your own timezone.

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Africa/Johannesburg /etc/localtime
```

Basically `/etc/localtime` should be linked your timezone.

Comment: If baffled, Mac uses FreeBSD zoneinfo.

Comment: After rebooting the MacBook, the warning shows up again.

Comment: Did anybody notice that this warning is not coming up anymore since emulator version 27.3.1?